# Background Image with opacity in tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to recreate a project from vanilla CSS to tailwindcss. But I tried a lot of options and failed badly.

This is the CSS code:

```
header {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9), rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9)), url(img/hero-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
}
```

Can anyone transform this code to the equivalent tailwindcss code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a few of options:

The easiest one is to set the image on the style property, after all this are very customized styles:

```
<header
  class="relative bg-fixed bg-center bg-cover bg-no-repeat"
  style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9), rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9)), url(img/hero-bg.jpg)">
  
</header>
```

The second option is to keep using your stylesheet as it is now, but only for the background-image:

```
header {
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9), rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9)), url(img/hero-bg.jpg)
}



<header class="relative bg-fixed bg-center bg-cover bg-no-repeat">
  
</header>
```

Finally, you can create a plugin where you can dynamically send the colors, and image as a parameter and tailwind will generate those classes for you. This is more complex but the documentation is really helpful: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#app

If you ask me, I'd just go with the first option

Here's a working demo and a tutorial: https://bleext.com/post/creating-a-hero-header-with-a-fixed-image

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. But why didn't tailwind's gradient CSS property work like this? Also, there's nothing like this in the documentation.

Comment: Right, I've written a tutorial for you answering these questions: https://bleext.com/post/creating-a-hero-header-with-a-fixed-image

Comment: I suggest to use css vars for colors and background urls. Using these css vars in tailwind config, you can benefit from shared theme config (static or tailwind way).

Answer (score 0):

I found a a great tool for converting regular CSS to Tailwindcss CSS utility classes at **https://transform.tools/css-to-tailwind**

```
`/*
  Based on TailwindCSS recommendations,
  consider using classes instead of the `@apply` directive
  @see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#avoiding-premature-abstraction
*/
header {
  @apply bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-[center_center] bg-fixed relative;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9), rgba(135, 80, 156, 0.9)),
    url(img/hero-bg.jpg);
}
```