# Color opacity on an image background

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I need to make a background with an image and a transparent color on top of that image, but I don't know how to do it. This is my code, I tried several changes, can anyone help me? I'm using tailwindcss

I have an image of a woman and I need to put an orange color on top of that image, and this color must have an opacity of 80

```
export default function Header({ children }) {
    return (
      <div className="bg-woman-img bg-center ">
          <div className="relative pt-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-12">
            <Nav />
            <div className="px-4 py-44 md:py-20">{children}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. `Opacity` is 80 in this example

```
 <div className="bg-woman-img bg-center bg-80">
```

Comment: It didn't work, I have the image of a woman and I need to put an orange color with opacity-80 on top

Comment: Take a look at this. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity

Answer (score 0):

For an opacity of 80 with TailWindCSS you would use opacity-80 on the div tag you would like to apply it to.

`<div className="bg-woman-img bg-center opacity-80">`

For making the background orange, you would probably have to add a custom color to your tailwindconfig file as TailWindCSS does not have a base orange. But from the documentation `bg-yellow-500` looks the closest.

Documentation for reference:

- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/opacity
- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put a color on top of the image, and that's where the opacity will be applied

Comment: Sorry just edited my answer to explain the color. Hmm I understand now, I seem to have found a similar question that has a solution that could help > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663368/background-image-with-opacity-in-tailwindcss